# How to convert existing images into Paperclip objects with existing associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm rebuilding an existing ASP app in Rails. I have many thousands of images stored on the current site's server that I'd like to import to my new database. The catch is, the photos are each associated with specific "Events" that my users create. For example, photos for event ID #250 are stored in ../data/photos/events/250/250-1.jpg (250-2.jpg, 250-3.jpg, and so on).

The event IDs are the same in the old database as the new one, as I've imported them directly from the old DB. Is there any way to import these old photos and associate them with their respective Events? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Paperclip adds an extra column to your database table to store the location of the file. For example:

```
add_column :products, :photo_file_name, :string
add_column :products, :photo_content_type, :string
add_column :products, :photo_file_size, :integer
add_column :products, :photo_updated_at, :datetime
```

Also, there is the `:path` option on `has_attached_file`

```
has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small => "150x150>" },
  :url => "/assets/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
  :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

From this tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip?view=asciicast

So you can make changes to match the same file path format you have in `../data/photos/events/250/250-1.jpg`